# How can I implement a navigation stack that, when I login, convert my master detail page in my main page and root

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation

I am developing an app in which I have a welcome page, a login page and a master detail page. I need that when logging to my users the master detail page is shown, which I already do, but my master detail page parace with the navigation bar typical of the arrow back on the menu hamburger abitual of the master details pages and if I click in the button back I return to my login page. How can I do that after logging my users my master detail page is my main page and the only one in my navigation stack so that they can not return to the login screen.

I have had an advance and it is that I have done:

```
var myMasterDetailPage = new MyMasterDEtailPage();
Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new myMasterDetailPage, 
Navigation.NavigationStack.FirstOrDefault());
Navigation.PopToRoot();
```

With the above when clicking on the back button my login page is no longer displayed (that's what I want), but I still see a strip above my burger menu on the master detail page, without an arrow but you can see, this I understand is because the instance of MyMasterDetailPage is still inside a NavigationPage.

PD: I use MessagingCenter for the communication between my viewmodel and my view, this communication works perfectly.

PD2: I tried App.Current.MainPage = myMasterDetailPage after Navigation.PopToRoot () but it does not work either.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new myMasterDetailPage ();
```

but be careful, this is the kind of things that are not reflected in xamarin live player.